# Can I set the background opacity of an image in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

The Tailwind docs [clearly show how to set the opacity of a background colour](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-opacity) but this does not seem to work when applying it to a background image.  For example:

```
<div class="bg-home-page-image bg-opacity-25">
```

Doesn't seem to change the opacity of the example image here for me.

Is there a way to achieve this in Tailwind?  Or would I need to create custom css like [this solution](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-a-css-background-images-opacity)

Comment: on tailwindcss bg-opacity classes is only for background color classes not for bg image

Comment: Try just using `opacity-25`

https://play.tailwindcss.com/52v7Tw8mkr

Comment: Sorry, I just realized this was for a background image.